# Nonrepresentability by radicals and entire (or meromorphic) functions of algebraic functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables, galois-theory, riemann-surfaces

It is known that an algebraic function with non-solvable monodromy group can not be represented by radicals. Where can we find a detailed proof about the nonrepresentability by radicals and entire (or meromorphic) functions of algebraic functions in some  English references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See e.g.:

- Vladimir Arnold: Collected Works. Springer
- [Khovanskii, A.: Topological Galois Theory - Solvability and Unsolvability of Equations in Finite Terms. Springer 2014](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-38871-2)
- [Khovanskii, A.: One dimensional topological Galois theory. 2019](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.03341)
- [Askold Khovanskii - Publications](https://www.math.toronto.edu/askold/)

For the topological proofs without connection to representability in meromorphic functions, see e.g.: [Is there an alternative proof of the Abel–Ruffini theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550990/is-there-an-alternative-proof-of-the-abel-ruffini-theorem).